# Inner content showing in column using display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center the content to the div using `display:flex` but the inner contents are showing in columns, not centered as well, how do I center the content vertically/horizontally and avoid this column like display?

Here is the code

```css
.gallery-1-main-info {
 width: 400px;
 float: left;
 background: #1f1f1f;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #a5a5a5;
 min-height: 590px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-1-main-info">
  <p class="grid-eng-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p class="grid-hin-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `width` & `float` from `.gallery-1-main-info` div. Check updated snippet below...

```css
.gallery-1-main-info {
 background: #1f1f1f;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #a5a5a5;
 min-height: 590px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-1-main-info">
  <p class="grid-eng-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p class="grid-hin-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the text within the `div` are still looking in columns..each paragraph is floated to left, instead it should show in next line

Comment: if you want all element show in rows then you can use `flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 1):

This will center the text using `display: inline-block;`

```css
.gallery-1-main-info {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    min-height: 590px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-1-main-info">
  <p class="grid-eng-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p class="grid-hin-title">Ruksat Title</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not vertically centered

Comment: Ypu put ```/``` so I thought you want either :P

Comment: Ohh, I am actually looking to center both, horizontally and vertically

Comment: Now seems as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the result you're expecting, centered horizontally and vertically. I had to add a content container, otherwise the `<p>` are covering all the available space.

```css
.gallery-1-main-info {
  min-height: 590px;
 background: #1f1f1f;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #a5a5a5;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.gallery-1-main-info .gallery-content {
 width: 400px;
  min-width: initial;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-1-main-info">

  <div class="gallery-content">
    <p class="grid-eng-title">Ruksat Title</p>
    <p class="grid-hin-title">Ruksat Title</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```